# Getting nullpointerException on creating new dialog in quickblox in android

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I am trying to make a chat application demo in android using quickblox,I have got a list of users successfully,and on click of usrlist i got its "id",I pass it to creating new chat dialog code,But it gives me Nullpointer at privatechatmanager.

my code is :

```
   public Integer getOpponentIDForPrivateDialog(QBDialog dialog){
        Integer opponentID = -1;
        for(Integer userID : dialog.getOccupants()){
            if(!userID.equals(getCurrentUser().getId())){
                opponentID = userID;
                break;
            }
        }
        return opponentID;
    }
```

**logcat**
06-16 17:11:07.817:

```
 I/System.out(32408): =============MY SELECTED USER==============3588999
06-16 17:11:07.847: D/AndroidRuntime(32408): Shutting down VM
06-16 17:11:07.847: W/dalvikvm(32408): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a3da0)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408): Process: com.amar.chums, PID: 32408
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at com.amar.chums.activity.ManageConnection$2.onItemClick(ManageConnection.java:154)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:313)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1507)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3514)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5072)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
06-16 17:11:07.847: E/AndroidRuntime(32408):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to save my life..!!!

Comment: put your logcat error here.

Comment: @dhuma1981-Yes sure..Please wait 1 min

Comment: Check whether `myConnections.get(position)` is not returning `null`

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj-i am successfully getting user_id on listItem's Click so no chance to getting null.

Comment: What's the code in line 154 of `ManageConnection.java`

Comment: There's a `NullPointerException` in line 154. what's on that line?

Comment: This is line number on which you are getting any null object.

Comment: @UmaKanth- privateChatManager.createDialog(
      Integer.parseInt(myConnections.get(position).get("id")), this line

Comment: @NKushwah - i know that thing better,But i want to know how to solve it,as i am using quickBlox and creating a dialog

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj- privateChatManager.createDialog(
      Integer.parseInt(myConnections.get(position).get("id")),

Comment: can you please show full code of itemClick()

Comment: myConnections.get(position).get("id")      -    Either myConnections or myConnections.get(position) is null

Comment: @JamesB-Its working fine,I am getting that value.so its not issue

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Answer (score 1):

try to handle the nullpointer

```
my_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            System.out
                    .println("=============MY SELECTED USER=============="
                            + myConnections.get(position).get("id"));
            QBDialog dialog = new QBDialog();
            dialog.setType(QBDialogType.PRIVATE);

            QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = QBChatService
                    .getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();

            // try to handle the null value of both object
            // i just discontinue the further code by returning the method ..do as per your requirement
            // try to re-instialize or find the case..why its happen
            if(privateChatManager == null || myConnections == null)
                return;

            privateChatManager.createDialog(
                    Integer.parseInt(myConnections.get(position).get("id")),
                    new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a validity check before both

> dialog.getOccupants()

**`and`**

> getCurrentUser().getId()

Make sure they have values in it.